# Want to start a long running process and then go directly to a page that will poll the database to report progress (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, process

I have read a couple articles with no clear idea of the right way to do this..  So my basic thinking is I can create a thread and run that and then have the controller go to another view... In that view I could have a jquery call to another method on the controller that check how many rows have been created every 5 seconds using a timer...  This make sense ?

I don't need a value returned from my call to the long running process.. I just need it to start and the next page will report on the progress...

So do I use the new async/await ? Task? Thread?

I guess I don't need to use async/await since I am not interested in a return value ?

EDIT:

So you are saying the code below is a bad thing becase that 'catch' will never occur since my code is off running and knows nothing about the httpcontext any more ?

```
   public ActionResult ValidateUnprocessedData()
    {
        //Check table for jobs to be started
        List<TaskInstance> taskInstancesNotStarted = InstanceExpert.GetAllTaskInstancesNotStarted();

        try
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ValidateProcesses(taskInstancesNotStarted));
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            InstanceErrorExpert.LogErrorGeneric(ex.Message);
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: The code above is not recommended. For one thing, the `catch` block won't catch any exceptions from `ValidateProcesses`. Also, this leaves `ValidateProcesses` running after `ValidateUnprocessedData` returns its view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (probably) don't want to execute a long-running process in ASP.NET because [it wasn't designed for it](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

You're better off using an actual worker service (e.g., Azure worker role or Win32 service) that places its results in persistent storage (e.g., Azure table). Then you can poll that using ASP.NET.